# Integrate both typescript and javascript files into angular same project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Would it be possible to have both typescript and javascript files in the same angular project?

I have a pretty big project in angular and I want to migrate it to typescript without renaming all files to .ts and fix the errors. 
Would it be possible to have only one part of an angular application written in typescript and the other one in javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible with the latest flag *--allowjs* in typescript 1.8.
You can modify your tsconfig.json to include it like this:

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": { 
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

See roadmap for more info: [Typescript 1.8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#18), and specifically here: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4792)